# Gestures on a textview in Android

Tags: android, textview, geometry, gestures

How can I have my textview detect if a circle is drawn on it's surface?  And help would be great.

Thanks so much.
-Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a GestureOverlayView to your application.

There is a nice walkthrough for gestures on the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Can it just be over the textview?  The textview only takes up about a third of the screen.

Comment: Also the user must still be able to tap and hold the TextView.

Comment: To my knowledge the gestures overlay will work on top of any other view. Just wrap the GestureOverlayView around a Textview.. it should work just fine..

Comment: Ok, I've done it but it is not meshing with my on touch and on hold.  Each one cancels the gesture.